# Simple template in PHP / Output buffering performance

Tags: php, buffer, template-engine, ob-start

I'm using in my script very simple template engine:

```
<?php
require_once('some_class.php');
$some_class = new some_class();

function view($file, $vars) {
    ob_start();
    extract($vars);
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file . '.php';
    $buffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $buffer;
}

echo view('template', array(
    'content' => some_class::content(),
    'pages' => some_class::pages(),
    'meta_title' => some_class::$meta_title,
    'meta_description' => some_class::$meta_description
));
?>
```

It worked well but my script grows bigger and i'm adding new functions and sometimes in some situations it take a lot time to load page. My webpage need to use external API sometime and there are delays. How can i rebuild this to work without output buffering?

Comment: You could *not* use output buffering in the `view()` function, and instead of calling `echo view('template', array());` just call the function itself. I assume you return the buffer because you sometimes want the rendered template as a string, in those cases you can use output buffering only there.

Comment: For example in template.php i have:
`<?php echo $meta_title; ?>`
...and i set this in some_class.php:
`<?php
class some_class {

 public static $meta_title;

 public static function content() {
  some_class::$meta_title = 'Meta title to display in template.php';
 }
}
?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no reason to use output buffering at all.

```
<?php
require_once('some_class.php');
$some_class = new some_class();

function view($file, $vars) {
    extract($vars);
    include dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $file . '.php';
}

view('template', array(
    'content' => some_class::content(),
    'pages' => some_class::pages(),
    'meta_title' => some_class::$meta_title,
    'meta_description' => some_class::$meta_description
));
?>
```

This does the same thing, without the buffer. If you need the rendered template as a string (which probably only happens in 1 place in your code), you can use output buffering only there:

```
ob_start();
view('template', array(
    'content' => some_class::content(),
    'pages' => some_class::pages(),
    'meta_title' => some_class::$meta_title,
    'meta_description' => some_class::$meta_description
));
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

If you need templates as a string more often, wrap this logic in another function:

```
function render($file, $vars) {
    ob_start();
    view($file, $vars);
    $buffer = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $buffer;
}
```